# What is {{ self }} in Jinja2 templating system

Tags: saltstack

On the SaltStack [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html#matching-grains-in-the-top-file): It is explained that:

```
'node_type:web':
  - match: grain
  - webserver

'node_type:postgres':
  - match: grain
  - database

'node_type:redis':
  - match: grain
  - redis

'node_type:lb':
  - match: grain
  - lb
```

Can be simplified in:

```
{% set node_type = salt['grains.get']('node_type', '') %}

{% if node_type %}
  'node_type:{{ self }}':
    - match: grain
    - {{ self }}
{% endif %}
```

Using Jinja2 templating system (if the 'node_type' grain variable has been set on the minion). I don't understand to what {{ self }} refers? Where does this variable come from?

Comment: "self" should be "node_type". I looked at the documentation again today (pointing to the 2015.8.0 version) or looking at the version on trunk on github https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/666108df17569bdd17a1fba333a863b97197ef2e/doc/topics/targeting/grains.rst it has already been corrected.

Comment: Right, seems more logical now :)